# How to get substring using Dojo and javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo, substring

Good Day,

I am a newbie learning Javascript & Dojo and I typically learn by picking apart other parts of running code.

I am confused as to how to get a substring value from the following code (from the [ArcGIS Sandbox](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=query_nomap)):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, IE=9, IE=10">
          <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
            on iOS devices-->
          <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
          <title>Query State Info without Map</title>

          <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.6/"></script>
          <script>
            dojo.require("esri.tasks.query");
            dojo.require("esri.map");

            var queryTask, query;
            require([
              "esri/tasks/query", "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
              "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"
            ], function(
              Query, QueryTask,
              dom, on
            ){
              queryTask = new QueryTask("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/5");

              query = new Query();
              query.returnGeometry = false;
              query.outFields = ["SQMI","STATE_NAME","STATE_FIPS","SUB_REGION","STATE_ABBR","POP2000","POP2007","POP00_SQMI","POP07_SQMI","HOUSEHOLDS","MALES","FEMALES","WHITE","BLACK","AMERI_ES","ASIAN","OTHER","HISPANIC","AGE_UNDER5","AGE_5_17","AGE_18_21","AGE_22_29","AGE_30_39","AGE_40_49","AGE_50_64","AGE_65_UP"];

              on(dom.byId("execute"), "click", execute);

              function execute(stateName) {
                query.text = dom.byId("stateName").value;
                //execute query
                queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
              }

              function showResults(results) {
                var s = "";
                for (var i=0, il=results.features.length; i<il; i++) {
                  var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;
                  for (att in featureAttributes) {
                    s = s + "<b>" + att + ":</b>  " + featureAttributes[att] + "<br>";
                  }
                  s = s + "<br>";
                }
                dom.byId("info").innerHTML = s;
              }
            });
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
          US state name : 
          <input type="text" id="stateName" value="California">
          <input id="execute" type="button" value="Get Details">
          <br />
          <br />
          <div id="info" style="padding:5px; margin:5px; background-color:#eee;">
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

All I would like to do is pick apart the input (in this case the id="stateName" which is the word California).

So a silly example would be substituting the following code to get the first 10 characters of when someone types in 'California is on the west coast'

```
     query.text = dom.byId("stateName").substring(0,10);
```

This is really so I can support other queries but I figured if I can do a substring on this input then it is really the same anytime when I query other attributes.

Thanks in advance for a newbie !

Comment: From `query.text = dom.byId("stateName").substring(0,10);` it seems you know how to do what you asked... you need to rephrase your question if you are unclear on something.

Comment: Hi Wyatt,  well I thought I knew something but when I used that substitution it does not work.  I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I commented on the answer below because the answer is so close. It should be `query.text = dom.byId("stateName").value.substring(0, 10);`. I've edited @DesertIvy's answer but it still needs to be peer-reviewed and accepted.

Comment: Hi Thomas,  Thanks - I was playing for about an hour and figured it out eventually...  substr also works.  I will create a new answer as while DesertIvy was close, the answer is buried in the comment

Comment: I have updated my answer with the more better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `innerHTML` of your DOM element

```
query.text = dom.byId("stateName").value.substring(0, 10);
```

Comment: If I substitute that for line 33 it does not appear to work.  Is 'substring' submethod valid for innherHTML ?

Comment: You don't need `innerHTML`, you need `value`: `query.text = dom.byId("stateName").value.substring(0, 10);`

Comment: You're right, I have updated my answer.

innerHTML is gross anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Upton correctly pointed out the correct form would be:

```
      dom.byId("stateName").value.substring(0, 10);
```

apparently the following also works

```
     dom.byId("stateName").value.substr(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, a call to `.value` will deliver what you need. Substring is a method on the string prototype [See here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) However, dom.byId [returns a domNode.](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/byId.html) You don't want the substring of the domNode itself, you want the substring of the text value of the domNode. On inputs this is easily done with `.value` and is commonly done with `.textContent` and `.innerHTML` as well.